# How to implement os share for Facebook in win32 application?

Tags: windows, facebook, winapi, wrl

I have a win32 application, which works on image editing. I have to implement a Facebook share through OS for an image.

I have already investigated in UWP application. This can be done using dataTransferManager (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager).
It shows a share panel with all the app which can accept the image. Facebook application is also shown in the share panel. After selecting Facebook, Facebook gets open and share dialog gets open inside Facebook with the image.

I have found code which can be used for sharing using WRL (https://github.com/arunjeetsingh/Build2015/tree/master/Win32ShareSourceSamples/Win32_Share_Desktop) but they have not added an image in dataTransferManager so the app like Facebook is not shown in the share panel. I didn't have a clear understanding of how to add an image in dataTransferManager using WRL.

I have two question:

1. Is image sharing can be done in a win32 app (classic) using share panel and dataTransferManager?
2. Can I get some helpful articles or any Github repository where it is actually done?

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm able to integrate the OS share panel in win32.
code can be found here:
https://github.com/vivek0739/Build2015/tree/master/Win32ShareSourceSamples/Win32_Share_Desktop

I have used WRL and COMPtr.